# How to use Rails DateHelper method time_ago_in_words outside of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I downloaded and installed the ActiveHelper gem, but I still can't figure out how to use ActionView's DateHelper methods, such as time_ago_in_words, in normal Ruby code. Is this not included in ActiveHelper? Is it possible to use these methods outside of Rails?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'action_view'
require 'action_view/helpers'
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 60*60*2) + ' ago'
#=> "about 2 hours ago"
```

If you need to take advantage of Numeric ActiveSupport extensions:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'
time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 2.hours) + ' ago'
#=> "about 2 hours ago"
# note that (Time.now - 2.hours) == (2.hours.ago)
```

Reference for **Non Rails App** : **https://github.com/elgalu/time_ago_in_words#non-rails-apps**

Comment: The gem you will need is [`actionview`](https://rubygems.org/gems/actionview/versions/4.2.5.1)

Comment: If you `require action_view`, doesn't that already include the `helpers` module?

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea what ActiveHelper is, but your underlying requirement is to have `time_ago_in_words` available in a non-Rails app then:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'action_view'
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

time_ago_in_words Time.now - 4 * 86400

# => "4 days"
```

Comment: Sorry, meant ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'
require 'action_view'
require 'action_view/helpers'
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

70.minutes.ago
# => 2015-02-23 09:09:04 +0530
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now)
#=> "3 minutes"
```

Comment: Why do you `require 'rubygems'`?